# Check if a file is or has been cloned

Tags: community, sandbox

I am working on an application where files will be cloned. I have a logic to be implemented now where a cloned file's category (A Field in the app) has to be set to Medium. Is there any way there is an inbuilt indicator that lets know if a file is cloned or being cloned?

Thanking you :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any such built-in functionality so the best way to handle this would be in your custom logic.

Comment: But that would mean i write a logic in a visual-force page. The problem now is that the page layouts and app has already been created and already running. I have to make this once change and add it to the rest.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution I can think of. Isn't the cloning logic already a part of your rest?